# Where to download Paket.fsx

Tags: f#, jupyter, paket

I'm trying to load a package using F# scripts on Jupyter notebook environment, using Paket package manager. All of the sample scripts on the web pointing to the use of "Paket.fsx" file.

My question is where do I get the "Packet.fsx" file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "modern" .NET (including F#) Jupyter Notebooks you won't be using `paket`. Take a look at one of the [explanatory blog posts by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNETJupyterNotebooks.aspx). You'll see that he (it is in C# but that's still valid for F#) always use a special syntax in the cells where imports happen

It looks like

```
#r "nuget:APackageName, 1.0.0"
#r "nuget:AnotherPackage, 2.0.0"
```

This does all the package referencing (including all the dark magic that makes .NET Standard work with .NET core in the Jupyter Kernel). There are a couple of [Binder notebooks](https://github.com/dotnet/try/blob/master/NotebooksOnBinder.md) in the source code repository for the .NET Core Jupyter Kernel. You might find more info there.

Answer (score 0):

Paket is an fsproject.

You can find info about it here:
https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/

And here is the Paket github:
https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket